# Tkinter, treeview doesn't resize

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

How can I make the treeview resize when I resize the window in height ?
I tried to set `sticky="sn"`, I tried to pack the treeview with `fill='y'`, but nothing worked.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import Treeview

root = tk.Tk()

f1 = tk.Frame(root)
f2 = tk.Frame(root)

f1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="s")
f2.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="n")
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

Treeview(f1).pack()
tk.Button(f2, text="DAT BUTTON IS IN F2").pack()
tk.Button(f2, text="DAT BUTTON IS IN F2").pack()
tk.Button(f2, text="DAT BUTTON IS IN F2").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need `sticky="ns"` to resize `Frame` in window and `fill='y', expand=True` to resize `Treeview` in `Frame`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import Treeview

root = tk.Tk()

f1 = tk.Frame(root)
f2 = tk.Frame(root)

f1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="ns")
f2.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="n")
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

Treeview(f1).pack(expand=True, fill='y')
tk.Button(f2, text="DAT BUTTON IS IN F2").pack()
tk.Button(f2, text="DAT BUTTON IS IN F2").pack()
tk.Button(f2, text="DAT BUTTON IS IN F2").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Dammit, I was so close haha. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full grid method equivalent:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import Treeview

root = tk.Tk()

f1 = tk.Frame(root)
f2 = tk.Frame(root)

f1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="ns")
f2.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="n")
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

Treeview(f1).grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ns')  # replaced pack with grid method
f1.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)  # Add this newline for Treeview to stretch vertically in f1. 
tk.Button(f2, text="DAT BUTTON IS IN F2").grid(row=0, column=0)
tk.Button(f2, text="DAT BUTTON IS IN F2").grid(row=1, column=0)
tk.Button(f2, text="DAT BUTTON IS IN F2").grid(row=2, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```