# Resizing Tree in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried making a Tree-Table in TKinter which is supposed to expand when I change the windows size. The original idea was from [Tkinter, treeview doesn't resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47934689/tkinter-treeview-doesnt-resize) ,from which I already copied some lines. However I need the tree to be accessible for later use, so I changed it to a variable. Does anyone know why it's not working anymore?

Heres the code, Thanks in advance!

```
from tkinter.ttk import Treeview

root = tk.Tk()

headlines = ["H1","H2","H3","H4","H5","H6","H7","H8"]


f1 = tk.Frame(root)
f1.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky="ns")
tree =Treeview(f1,show = ["headings"])
tree['columns'] = headlines

#naming Headlines
for i in headlines:
    tree.heading(i,text=i)
        
tree.pack(expand=True,fill='y')

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a column or row stretchable, use `rowconfigure` or `columnconfigure`, and supply a value that gives the relative weight of this column or row when distributing the extra space.

A simple solution would be to just apply these on the root object, like so

```py
from tkinter.ttk import Treeview
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

headlines = ["H1", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6", "H7", "H8"]

f1 = tk.Frame(root)
f1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="ns")
tree = Treeview(f1, show=["headings"])
tree['columns'] = headlines

# naming Headlines
for i in headlines:
    tree.heading(i, text=i)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

tree.pack(expand=True, fill='y')

root.mainloop()
```

For more info see [tkinter/grid-config](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/grid-config.html)