# Resize tkinter treeView

Tags: python, tkinter, grid-layout

How can I resize the treeView in Tkinter Python

The table might be here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHgLV.jpg)

I'm getting this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfBqT.png)

Here's the code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

white = "#FFFFFF"

window = Tk()
window.geometry("640x415")

listframe=Frame(
    window,
    bg=white
)

listframe.grid(
    row=1,
    column=1,
    sticky='NSEW'
)


  listFields = ['First name','Last name', 'Number', 'Email']
    tree = ttk.Treeview(listframe,columns=listFields)
    tree.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")  # columnspan=2 goes here.

    scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(listframe)
    scroll.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="nse")  # set this to column=2 so it sits in the correct spot.

    scroll.configure(command=tree.yview)
    tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

    listframe.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    listframe.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
window.resizable(False, False)
window.mainloop()
```

I can't resize the TreeView, it covers the left frame

Comment: Try looking at [Tkinter, treeview doesn't resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47934689/tkinter-treeview-doesnt-resize).

Comment: The code in your question doesn't create either of the images in your question.

Comment: @BryanOakley I just copied the part of treeView, not the whole code

Comment: We don’t need the whole code, but we do need enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have a look at this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63536506/13629335). You most certainly have done something wrong here and you would need to provide that layout to us in order to get specific help.

Comment: OK I added the code, I couldn't edit my post , it said "it's mostly code, add more details"

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

bgcolor1="#FFB6C1"
bgcolor2="#FFEACC"
grey = "#606060"
chalk = "Chalkduster"
white = "#FFFFFF"
black = "#000000"

window = Tk()
window.geometry("640x415")

window.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
window.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)

window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
window.rowconfigure(1, weight=8)
window.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)


pinkframe=Frame(window,bg=bgcolor1)
pinkframe.grid(
    row=0,
    column=0,
    rowspan=3,
    sticky='WENS'
)

searchFrame=Frame(
    window,
    bg=bgcolor2
)

searchFrame.grid(
    row=0,
    column=1,
    sticky='WENS'
)

listframe=Frame(
    window,
    bg=white
)

listframe.grid(
    row=1,
    column=1,
    sticky='NSEW'
)


delFrame=Frame(
    window,
    bg=bgcolor2
)

delFrame.grid(
    row=2,
    column=1,
    sticky='WENS'
)

welcome = Label(
    pinkframe,
    text="Welcome!",
    height=1,
    font=(chalk, 30),
    fg=black,
    bg=bgcolor1
)
welcome.place(x=80,y=5)

addNew = Label(
    pinkframe,
    text="Add new contact",
    height=1,
    font=(chalk, 18),
    fg=black,
    bg=bgcolor1
)
addNew.place(x=70,y=100)



#First name

fName = Label(
    pinkframe,
    text="First name",
    height=1,
    font=(chalk, 13),
    fg=grey,
    bg=bgcolor1
)
fName.place(x=8,y=140)

fEntry = Entry(
    pinkframe,
    width=20,
    justify='left',
    relief = "ridge",
    highlightthickness=0
)
fEntry.place(x=100,y=140)


#Last name

lName = Label(
    pinkframe,
    text="Last name",
    height=1,
    font=(chalk, 13),
    fg=grey,
    bg=bgcolor1
)
lName.place(x=8,y=180)

lEntry = Entry(
    pinkframe,
    width=20,
    justify='left',
    relief = "ridge",
    highlightthickness=0
)
lEntry.place(x=100,y=180)


#Phone number

pNum = Label(
    pinkframe,
    text="Phone",
    height=1,
    font=(chalk, 13),
    fg=grey,
    bg=bgcolor1
)
pNum.place(x=8,y=220)

pEntry = Entry(
    pinkframe,
    width=20,
    justify='left',
    relief = "ridge",
    highlightthickness=0
)
pEntry.place(x=100,y=220)



#email

eMail = Label(
    pinkframe,
    text="email",
    height=1,
    font=(chalk, 13),
    fg=grey,
    bg=bgcolor1
)
eMail.place(x=8,y=260)

eEntry = Entry(
    pinkframe,
    width=20,
    justify='left',
    relief = "ridge",
    highlightthickness=0
)
eEntry.place(x=100,y=260)


#add
addButton= Button(
    pinkframe,
    text="ADD",
    height=2,
    bg = "#FF5FDB",
    fg = black,
    font=(chalk,16 ))
addButton.place(x=150,y=300)

searchEntry = Entry(
    searchFrame,
    width=25,
    justify='left',
    relief = "ridge",
    highlightthickness=0
)
searchEntry.place(x=10,y=8)

searchButton= Button(
    searchFrame,
    text="Search",
    height=1,
    bg = "#FF5FDB",
    fg = black,
    font=(chalk,10))
searchButton.place(x=245,y=7)


editButton= Button(
    listframe,
    text="Edit",
    height=1,
    bg = "#FF5FDB",
    fg = black,
    font=(chalk,10))
editButton.place(x=260,y=0)

#contacts list

def showList():
    global tree

    listFields = ['First name','Last name', 'Number', 'Email']
    tree = ttk.Treeview(listframe,columns=listFields)
    tree.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")  # columnspan=2 goes here.

    scroll = ttk.Scrollbar(listframe)
    scroll.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="nse")  # set this to column=2 so it sits in the correct spot.

    scroll.configure(command=tree.yview)
    tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

    listframe.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    listframe.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    tree.heading(0,text='First name', anchor=NW)
    tree.column("#0", anchor=CENTER, stretch=NO, width=80)

    tree.heading(1, text='Last name', anchor=NW)
    tree.column("#1", anchor=CENTER, stretch=NO, width=80)


    tree.heading(2, text='Phone', anchor=NW)
    tree.column("#2", anchor=CENTER, stretch=NO, width=80)


    tree.heading(3, text='Email', anchor=NW)
    tree.column("#3", anchor=CENTER, stretch=NO, width=80)

showList()

window.resizable(False, False)
window.mainloop()
```